# How to get a click function to work for only the class of the object you clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have several buttons that use the same class. I am using a click function to make adjustments to the button. The issue I am having is the click function is controlling all of the buttons with the same class.

I am using `$(document.body)` as the selector because the data is derived asynchronously.

I'm wanting to toggle the class for both the `triggerPosition` and `triggerButton`. Originally, I just had `$(document.body).on('click', '.triggerButton', function() {` and thought adding 'triggerPosition' into it would allow the `$(this)` function to work for both the `triggerPosition` and `triggerButton`, but it doesn't.

Does anyone see what I need to do? The `triggerButton` is working for the specific one clicked on. Currently, the `triggerPosition` is the issue.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.triggerButton', '.triggerPosition', function() {
  $('.triggerPosition').toggleClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.triggerRow {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  width: 500px;
}

.triggerButton {
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  border: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.triggerButton.active {
  background: #b82222;
}

.triggerPosition {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #4d4d4d;
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.triggerPosition.active {
  border: 2px solid #b82222;
  transform: translateX(21px);
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="triggerRow" data-triggerid="1">
  <div class="triggerButton">
    <div class="triggerPosition"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="triggerRow" data-triggerid="2">
  <div class="triggerButton">
    <div class="triggerPosition"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is a typographical error. The selector needs to be in a single string, ie. `'.triggerButton', '.triggerPosition'` => `'.triggerButton, .triggerPosition'`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ahh ok. Thanks. When I click on this I still see the other button(s) engage periodically.

Comment: Then if I click only on the `triggerButton` it only toggles the class for that. Is there a way that if the user clicks on `triggerButton` or `triggerPosition` that they toggle uniformly?